# Is there a better way? SQL query

Tags: sql, wordpress

I need to get data from database of the next type:

| post_id | meta_key1 | meta_key2 | meta_key3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | meta_value1 | meta_value2 | meta_value3 |
| 2 | meta_value1 | meta_value2 | meta_value3 |

Where meta_key1, meta_key2 and meta_key3 come from the same table. Here is my version of the query:

```
SELECT posts.ID AS post_id, meta1.meta_value AS meta_key1, meta2.meta_value AS meta_key2, 
meta3.meta_value AS meta_key3
FROM `wp_posts` AS posts 
JOIN `wp_postmeta` AS meta1 ON meta1.post_id = posts.ID 
JOIN `wp_postmeta` AS meta2 ON meta2.post_id = posts.ID
JOIN `wp_postmeta` AS meta3 ON meta3.post_id = posts.ID
WHERE meta1.meta_key = 'meta_key1' 
AND meta2.meta_key = 'meta_key2'
AND meta3.meta_key = 'meta_key3'
```

Is there a better option?

Comment: Please tag your question with the DBMS you are using. Also add the CREATE TABLE statements for wp_posts and wp_postmeta and provide sample data for these 2 tables that will result in the output you have given in your question

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with that query.

I usually put the all of the JOIN predicates together, rather than having some in the JOIN and some in the WHERE clause. But with an inner join, the result should be the same:

```
SELECT posts.ID AS post_id, meta1.meta_value AS meta_key1, meta2.meta_value AS meta_key2, 
meta3.meta_value AS meta_key3
FROM `wp_posts` AS posts 
    JOIN `wp_postmeta` AS meta1 ON meta1.post_id = posts.ID AND meta1.meta_key = 'meta_key1'
    JOIN `wp_postmeta` AS meta2 ON meta2.post_id = posts.ID AND meta2.meta_key = 'meta_key2'
    JOIN `wp_postmeta` AS meta3 ON meta3.post_id = posts.ID AND meta3.meta_key = 'meta_key3'
```